# Stream filter didn't work well I want to print 10 lines

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why doesn't this stream stop from printing `1` despite we have a filter?

Can someone explain it to me? This example is not accurate and the best example for manipulating streams, it's just for learning purposes.

```
Stream.generate(() -> "1")
                .peek(System.out::println)
                .filter(x -> x.length() > 1)
                .limit(10)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The correct one is :

```
Stream.generate(() -> "1")
                .limit(10)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: If you just want a 10-element stream, IntStream.range(0,10) is probably a better place to start.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of a stream as pipeline. Elements will keep coming out from the `generate` method. Each element is then passed through each subsequent operation.

So in your code:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "1")
            .peek(System.out::println)
            .filter(x -> x.length() > 1)
            .limit(10)
            .forEach(System.out::println);
```

The following keeps going:

- A new `"1"` is generated
- At `peek`, your `"1"` is printed
- At `filter`, if `"1"`'s length is larger than 1, it will come through, otherwise it will be thrown away
- If the `"1"` comes through the filter, it will reach limit. The limit only will let the first 10 elements through. After the 10th element, it will throw the element away

No elements will pass through the filter, because `"1"`'s length is never larger than 1. The `limit` never lets enough elements through and so the terminal operation is not reached, it never terminates.

That's why it keeps on repeating the first two lines.

I'll now explain why reversing the order of `limit` and `filter` works:

```
Stream.generate(() -> "1")
        .peek(System.out::println)
        .limit(10)
        .filter(x -> x.length() > 1)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Only 10 elements will be printed first by `peek` then come through the `limit` bit. Then all those 10 elements does not come through the `filter`. But this time, the terminal operation is reached because `filter` is not like `limit`, which waits for 10 elements before carrying on. The whole thing terminates and no more elements is generated.

Answer (score 1):

From the doc, the method `generate` returns an infinite sequence of you ask it to do :

```
static <T> Stream<T> generate(Supplier<T> s)
```

> Returns an infinite sequential unordered stream where each element is generated by the provided Supplier. This is suitable for generating constant streams, streams of random elements, etc.

So `Stream.generate(() -> "1").peek(System.out::println)` never stops

You'll have also this but it 'll print nothing because of the `filter`

```
.filter(x -> x.length() > 1)
.limit(10)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

---

To print `1` ten times :

```
Stream.generate(() -> "1").limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
// OR
IntStream.generate(() -> 1).limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: yes but why when I change .filter(x -> x.length() > 1) with .limit(10) it works and print 10 elements

Answer (score 1):

What do you expect actually?

```
Stream.generate(() -> "1") // generates a String of length one
            .peek(System.out::println) // prints it
            .filter(x -> x.length() > 1) // filters those that have length bigger than one
            .limit(10) // this is NEVER reached
            .forEach(System.out::println); // this is NEVER reached
```

Since the terminal operation is never hit, the stream keeps generating elements, well, forever.

The second example on the other hand does not suffer from this, there is no `filter` and limit - after 10 elements hits its bound.

Comment: it is not correct that the last two methods are not reached (executed). They will be executed, but the sequence of elements is empty when they are applied.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko yeah, thats what I meant... Thank u

Answer (score -1):

You peek before you filter, that's why your filter does not apply before printing.

Comment: I think peek is for debugging purposes, isn't it? so it's not a terminal operation

Comment: Maybe it is used for debugging, but that's why your first snippet prints 1 infinitely.

Comment: and why when I change the order of  .filter(x -> x.length() > 1) and .limit(10) it works and prints 10 elements

Comment: Problem of the first listing is the peek. In your second listing you should see exactly 10 lines. If you add the filter before the limit, then you'll have an infinite production of "1" which are all consumed by the filter and no line will ever printed, nor will the limit ever apply.